# wordpress admin curl login wont work

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am trying to access my wordpress's admin section via curl but all i get is a blank page. What am i doing wrong? here is the script

```
$username="username";
$password="password";
$url="http://www.socialzend.com";
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$postdata = "log=". $username ."&pwd=". $password ."&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to=". $url ."wp-admin/&testcookie=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "/wp-login.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url . "wp-admin/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: What does echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($tuCurl); say?

Comment: i tried it as echo curl_error($ch) and the page shows blank. i was also missing a / in wp-login.php

Comment: i found out the issue, i removed www in the domain and it worked. thanks for your help.